# How to convert string variables into TXT file without the appearance of the additional brackets in matlab?

Tags: matlab, txt

I have (1 x 1 cell) with just one variable:   TEXT1 = 'I am Text';

I wanted to use the following command to attempt a cell to txt file conversion:

writecell(TEXT1, 'Testdocument.txt');

However one I open up the Txt file itself I get some additional " " quote:

"I am text"

this is quite unusable in these line further as a makro. So i would like to know if there is a better command without those " " quote?

Comment: `" "` are double quotes. `[ ]` are brackets. `"abc"` is a string. `'abc'` is a character array: [Characters and Strings](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"abc"` is a string. `'abc'` is a character array: [Characters and Strings](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/characters-and-strings.html)

You can convert a character array to a string with

```
string('abc') % "abc"
```

and a string to a character array with

```
char("abc") % 'abc'
```

`TEXT1 = 'I am Text';` creates a char array. You can't use

```
writecell(TEXT1, 'Testdocument.txt');
```

with a char array. You can use

```
TEXT1 = 'I am Text';
writematrix(TEXT1, 'Testdocument.txt');
```

or

```
TEXT1 = 'I am Text';
writecell({TEXT1}, 'Testdocument.txt');
```

or

```
TEXT1 = {'I am Text'};
writecell(TEXT1, 'Testdocument.txt');
```

All versions create a text document without double quotes (`" "`):

```
I am Text
```

Comment: neat and simple. Thank you!